# How can I use pyzmq and trollius together?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pyzmq

The [`trollius` library](http://trollius.readthedocs.org) is a Python 2 port of Python 3's [`asyncio` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).  The Python 3 version benefits from third part libraries like `aiohttp` and [`aiozmq`](http://aiozmq.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7.0/) that aid integration with various protocols

If I want to use the trollius port (I have to support Python 2 users) then what is the best way to integrate with ZeroMQ?  Futures?

Comment: Since `aiozmq` is Python 3-only, your only option (aside from trying to backport `aiozmq`) is probably to use `pyzmq` inside a background thread, using [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) to avoid blocking the event loop.

Comment: aiozmq (as well as aiohttp) doesn't work with trollius and will never do.